# How to consume data from a Apache Kafka

Tags: apache-kafka, consumer, confluent-cloud

Participating in a chalenge, it says like: *Your first step - consume data sample from a Apache Kafka.*
So they give me **topic name**, **API_KEY** and **API_SECRET**. Oh, and **bootstrap server**.
Then they claim as if you unfamiliar with Kafka, there is comprehensive documentation provided by Confluent. So ok, sign in to confluent, make a cluster and.. what is the next step to consume data ?

Comment: Are you wanting to do this programmatically, from the command line, or web interface?

Comment: Prefer web interface.
The idea was to download data sample and then using Python make model to predict churn/retention. I am familair working with .csv via jupyternotebooks, but here total newbie how to extract data from streaming platforms.

Comment: So it sounds like you're asking how to ingest data from Kafka into Python?

Comment: For sure, but I am also wondering why I need Confluent cluster for this. I watched couple of their tutorials but did not find out how to ingest it. At least it is not tangible / clear for me now what to begin with.

Comment: Confluent Cloud provides a managed Apache Kafka service. You could run Apache Kafka yourself locally if you want to. I'm not clear what you're starting point is here. Perhaps you can link to the tutorial/challenge that you're working on?

Comment: Kafka consumers works fine in Jupyter too, btw. Not clear what service your API key is for, though

Comment: https://challenge.cloud.sebgroup.com/#/startpage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a basic pattern for putting messages from Kafka into a list in Python.

```
from kafka import KafkaConsumer

consumer = KafkaConsumer(
    'someTopicName',
     bootstrap_servers=['192.168.1.160:9092'],
     auto_offset_reset='earliest',
     enable_auto_commit=True,
     group_id='my-group',
     value_deserializer=lambda x: loads(x.decode('utf-8')))
print("We have a consumer instantiated")
print(consumer)

messageCache = []

for message in consumer:
    messageCache.append(message.value)
```

In this case, my Kafka broker is on my private LAN, using the default port, so my bootstrap servers list is just ["192.168.1.160:9092"].

You can use standard counters and if statements to save the list to file or whatever, since the Kafka stream is assumed to run forever.   For example, I have a process that consumes Kafka messages and saves them as a dataframe in parquet to HDFS for every 1,000,000 messages.    In this case I was wanting to save historical messages to develop an ML model.    The great thing about Kafka is that I could write another process that evaluated and potentially responded to every message in real time.